# Problem with radarchart using fmbs library

Tags: r, radar-chart

I'm helping a friend making figures to her publication. She need radar charts, send me the data. I'm using fmsb library in R, but have some problem. The data is the following (some modified, because it's unpublished :) )

| consequences | timeline | personal control | treatment | control | identity | concern | comprehensibility | emotions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Min | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Max | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| Mean | 7.74 | 6.14 | 5.2 | 2.82 | 7.12 | 7.18 | 2.44 | 7.26 |

The code:

```
radarchart(chaos_story2,
  axistype = 4, 
  axislabcol = "black",
  seg = 5, 
  caxislabels= c(0,2,4,6,8,10), 
  cglcol="black")
```

[image]

The problem, that it seems the radarchart use the 1-mean values to plot the means, not the actual values. How I can solve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the min and max rows are in the wrong order. According to the docs `?radarchart`:

> If maxmin is TRUE, this must include **maximum values as row 1** and **minimum values as row 2** for each variables, and actual data should be given as row 3 and lower rows.

Fixing the order gives the desired result.

Note: There is probably an issue with your example data, i.e. I dropped the `consequences` column as it contained the rownames.

```r
library(fmsb)

# Max has to be first row, min the second
chaos_story2 <- chaos_story2[c(2, 1, 3), ]

radarchart(chaos_story2,
           axistype = 4, 
           axislabcol = "black",
           seg = 5, 
           caxislabels= c(0,2,4,6,8,10), 
           cglcol="black")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
chaos_story2 <- data.frame(
       consequences = c("Min", "Max", "Mean"),
           timeline = c(0, 10, 7.74),
   personal.control = c(0, 10, 6.14),
          treatment = c(0, 10, 5.2),
            control = c(0, 10, 2.82),
           identity = c(0, 10, 7.12),
            concern = c(0, 10, 7.18),
  comprehensibility = c(0, 10, 2.44),
           emotions = c(0, 10, 7.26)
)

rownames(chaos_story2) <- chaos_story2$consequences
chaos_story2$consequences <- NULL
``
```

Comment: Why on the original spider chart the lines are somehow distorted (see the line segment from personal.control to treatment.control), while in the improved version (see answer 1) spider chart is not distorted? I have the problem with distorted line on my own spider chart.